# Any recommended ways to debug vimscript?

Tags: vimscript, debugging

I'm interested in different ways to debug/trace or/and see the execution in real time (a la `bash -x`) vimscript.

Comment: start reading at `:h debug-scripts`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In an extremely related Q/A, I've listed all the tools I provide and use to help tracking errors in vim scripts: https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/25863/626

They complement `:debug`.

Comment: Very nice! One question though: you mentioned on your post that `:debug` isn't perfect, and would be better if Vim was multi-threaded...but doesn't Vim have async support now? Can `:debug` profit from it?

Comment: Unfortunately no. I don't know the specifics. Somehow, Vim _async_ implementation is equivalent to processes in the background with asynchronous communication. Vim kernel isn't multithreaded. I don't know whether it's done with polling or interruptions when something is received. What I observe is that when a message is received, normal processing is interrupted the time the message is being handled, then resumed.

Comment: Gotcha! That's very informative. Hopefully we'll see a real hyper-threaded support in the near future.

Comment: That's unlikely :(

Comment: UI thread is necessarily single threaded anyway, and the majority of Vim plugins and functions are constantly working on the UI, either capturing input or changing the screen. Multithreading UI makes writing code and plugins much harder to get right, and is not going to be faster since you'll have to take lots of fine grained locks, which will actually slow things down. The only thing you can multithread are generally computationally heavy tasks that doesn't involve much UI interaction and for those, you can just use message passing, aka async communications to a separate process just fine.

Comment: Multithreading would have permitted to do heavy Vim tasks in the background like highlighting 100k which easily blocks Vim for several seconds. Also some other MT-related features would have been nice like atomic operations or lock -- I'd have welcomed them to really make sure there only one async task that updates the qf-window for instance. Once started, everything stops: we cannot see how windows or buffers are updated, we cannot watch variables... /// Back to debug, the problem is that debug sessions are modal.  It's possible I'm wrong that Multithreading would have helped solve it.